# How to get edited data on page reload in MVC app

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

So i have a div  which is editable, now after i edit div and refresh page i want page to show up edited data and not the original one.

Comment: Can you use `RedirectToAction` so that after the model is posted and data is saved it will redirect to the Get `Careers` Action which will intern get the latest data and display it.

Comment: Any little code or demo would be very help full.Voting you up for answer. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error when you try to post the form? Do you have the `@using(Html.BeginForm())` in your view?

Comment: No i don't have @using(Html.BeginForm()) in my view. And no error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the sample code. You might need to make necessary changes in the code based on your model and action definitions. To show the edited values I have stored the model in the session. But you can retrieve it through your datastore. You can also use `TempData` if you want to pass on the model to the subsequent action after redirection.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel mod;
    if (Session["Model"] != null)
    {
         mod = (MyModel)Session["Model"];
    }
    else
    {
        mod = new MyModel { SelectedValue = "10" };
    }
    return View(mod);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult PostModel(MyModel mod)
{
    if (mod != null)
    {
        mod.SelectedValue = mod.SelectedValue + "From PostModel";
        Session["Model"] = mod;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is a view

```
@model MVC3Stack.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostModel", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.SelectedValue)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nilesh will try it out, as you can see in JS fiddle  i have provided View,now when i click on EDIT then after that on DONE the data should get saved?? Anything i need to do on Done click???

Comment: Sir Did you have a look at my jsfiddle??

Comment: You just want to save the content?

Comment: Let me explain you Sir, now the div i have in fiddle when i click on edit the div becomes editable, now after editing and clicking on done when we refresh the page i want the page to show edited data and not the  unedited data. Thanks

Comment: The content cannot be posted back to the server. For this you might want to declare a hidden field. This hidden field will hold the content i.e. the inner html of your main div. and after submit you would get that content back on to the server, and update your model and then just use a `RedirectToAction` which will load the latest data.

Comment: Would you help me out with it sir please?? I have posted whatever i have coded so far. What else i need to do?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. You also need to add `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute if you are posting html back to the server. Although I want to make you aware that you make your site vulnerable to of html injection and XSS attacks. By default asp.net has a mechanism to prevent such data from being posted back to the application.

Comment: Sorry I thought I update the one you created here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HKybG/3/)

Comment: Thanks, so now how will i show edited data after refresh

Comment: The rest of the code remains same. Only thing you need is the `[ValidateInput(false)]` filter on your Post method.

Comment: Well it is not working. I modified code a bit but to no avail.:( Should i post me edited code???

Comment: You need to try the code that I posted, which will give you an idea on how it works. Try putting a break point on the post method and you would see that the HTML that is posted from the text box reaches the server and then again is shown back in the view.

Comment: I tried your code and modified as per my model and action, but not working. Can i mail you personally?? I did put a break point but it never reaches there :(